# flexbox properties to align icon and text in one div

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I am new to flexbox and I have difficulties to align an icon and text in one row.
I have a foot with email addres and phone number, I want to add icons to the text lines.

Here is a screenshot about the footer I have now where you can see that the icon and text is not aligned:
[image]

this is my html file:

```
<ng-container>
  <div class="content-footer-container">
    <div class="first-text-block">
      <span class="material-icons">
        mail_outline
      </span>
      <a href="mailto:{{ supportInfo.emailAddress }}"> {{ supportInfo.name }}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="second-text-block">
      <span class="material-icons">
        phone
      </span>
      <span class="">{{ supportInfo.phoneNr }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="third-text-block">
      <span class="">{{ supportInfo.applicationName }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

and this is my css:

```
.content-footer-container {
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.material-icons {
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.first-text-block{
  flex:1;
  order:1;

  a {
    text-decoration:none
  }
}
```

I hope somebody can help me or point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 3):

```
.first-text-block, second-text-block, third-text-block {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

would be better to just give them the same class name

e.g.

```
.icon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```